# Using Tweepy to grab grab coordinates and plot them

Tags: python, matplotlib, tweepy

I am using tweepy to grab the tweets of users. Take their coordinates and then plot them on a map. Unfortunately I am new to Python and I am not sure why my program is not working. I got it to correctly grab the coordinates of all the users with certain keywords, but I am having trouble plotting it. When I run my code it's just saying "global name "on status" is not defined"

Any idea what's wrong with it? Also, should I be making the plotting a separate function? Ideally I would like my program to grab all the tweets for about 10 minutes, stop grabbing the tweets and plot the points, but I am not sure how to do that.

Here's the code:

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import json
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser


ckey = '
csecret = '
atoken = '
asecret = '

m = Basemap(projection='mill', llcrnrlat=20, urcrnrlat=50,\
        llcrnrlon=-130, urcrnrlon=-60, resolution ='c')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries()



twitterStream.filter(track=["justin", "bieber"])
```

Comment: Why have you removed most of the code, isn't relevant anymore? Even tough the accepted answer refers to some code, you had removed. Editing the question should only happen without changing the meaning, not providing the final answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you do not need this line:

```
on_event = on_status
```

If you actually need this you would probably want:

```
on_event = self.on_status
```

Comment: It appears that may have helped. It's giving me everyone's coordinates but It's  saying "failure, global name 'lon' is not defined" after every coordinate output.  Also I still do not have a map popping up which kinda concerns me.

Comment: `x,y = m(lon, lat)` is also wrong it should be `x,y = m(latitude, longitude)`.  That error means you are missing variable names so check that the variables at the given line are defined

Comment: Awesome. It looks like it's working. The only thing I can't get to work now is the map. Any idea why it's not popping up? It seems like it should pop up after I do the m.plot(), but no map is popping up.